# Emulating an ARRAY of Booleans while using SQLite3 in Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am writing a web server with Flask using Flask-SQLAlchemy as ORM. For the sake of simplicity, I want to use SQLite3 and store the state of the server in a simple file.

My data-model need to deal with a vector of booleans (fixed size known at DB creation), but it seems that the SQLAlchemy `ARRAY` type is not fully implemented for the SQLite3 backend.

Here is a simple run in the Python interactive shell that will demonstrate the problem:

```
>>> from flask import Flask
>>> from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
>>> app = Flask(__name__)
>>> app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite://'
>>> db = SQLAlchemy(app)
>>> class Sample(db.Model):
...     id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
...     task_done = db.Column(db.ARRAY(db.Boolean, dimensions=10))
... 
>>> db.create_all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/lib/python3/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 77, in _compiler_dispatch
    meth = getter(visitor)
AttributeError: 'SQLiteTypeCompiler' object has no attribute 'visit_ARRAY'
```

So, what could be the best workaround to use a list of booleans? I already tried to use a string with each character representing `True` or `False`, but I find this quite unsatisfactory...

Any better way to do it ?

EDIT: I already found this [blog post](http://davidemoro.blogspot.fr/2014/10/sqlite-array-type-and-python-sqlalchemy.html). But, it seems overly complex for such a little (though, I might be wrong with my little knowledge of the problem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I admit that the `ARRAY` type seems to be quite nice and obvious for databases. But, I discovered that this is not a standard type from the plain SQL specification... Indeed, it seems that only PostGreSQL does have it.

So, I ended up to not use the `ARRAY` type in my DB model... which is probably the worst workaround ever but, yet, the more compliant to the SQL standard.